# Recurrent neural network, time series prediction with newer Tensorflow 1.14

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

How to use new tf.keras API with recurrent neural network? I have checked the documentation but there is no example of such a situation.
There is this great book Hands on machine learning from 2017. Since that year the API of tensorflow has evolved and I am trying to rewrite recurrent neural network for time series prediction with using version `1.14` code.
The code from the book is using older `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` and `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell`:

```
n_steps = 20
n_inputs = 1
n_neurons = 100
n_outputs = 1
learning_rate = 0.001

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_outputs])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons])
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
n_iterations = 500
batch_size = 50

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
        for iteration in range(n_iterations):
        X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(batch_size, n_steps)
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        if iteration % 100 == 0:
            mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            print(iteration, "\tMSE:", mse)

    X_new = time_series(np.array(t_instance[:-1].reshape(-1, n_steps, n_inputs)))
    y_pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_new})
```

And this code works just fine (except that it throws warnings about deprecation left and right). I wanted to use `tf.keras` API as suggested in warning. My code is the same except:

```
cell =  tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)  
rnn_outputs = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,dtype=tf.float32, name="hidden1")(X)
```

But this yields following exception:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 50 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 20
 [[node Reshape_1 (defined at <ipython-input-9-879361be49dd>:3) ]]
```

so I understand that the problematic line is

```
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
```

After checking and comparing documentation for both cells https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn and 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN I can't find the culprit.

**What is the difference with these two cells? How to use tf.keras API with time series?**

Full old code: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/14_recurrent_neural_networks.ipynb

Full "my" code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from utils import shuffle_batch, variable_summaries
import os


dir_path = os.getcwd()

now = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
root_logdir = "tf_logs"
logdir = "{}/run-{}/".format(root_logdir, now)
print(dir_path)


t_min, t_max = -5, 5
section_start = (t_max + t_min) / 2
resolution = 0.1
n_steps = 20

def time_series(t):
    return np.sin(t)

def next_batch(batch_size, n_steps):
    t0 = np.random.rand(batch_size, 1) * (t_max - t_min - n_steps * resolution)
    Ts = t0 + np.arange(0., n_steps + 1) * resolution
    ys = time_series(Ts)
    return ys[:, :-1].reshape(-1, n_steps, 1), ys[:, 1:].reshape(-1, n_steps, 1)


t = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, int((t_max - t_min) / resolution))

t_instance = np.linspace(start = section_start, stop = section_start + resolution * (n_steps + 1),num = n_steps + 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(11,4))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("A time series (generated)", fontsize=14)
plt.plot(t, time_series(t), label=r"original")
plt.plot(t_instance[:-1], time_series(t_instance[:-1]), "b-", linewidth=3, label="A training instance")
plt.legend(loc="lower left", fontsize=14)
#plt.axis([-10, 10, -17, 13])
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Value")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title("A training instance", fontsize=14)
plt.plot(t_instance[:-1], time_series(t_instance[:-1]), "bo", markersize=10, label="instance")
plt.plot(t_instance[1:], time_series(t_instance[1:]), "c*", markersize=10, label="target")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlabel("Time")


# In[6]:


n_steps = 20
n_inputs = 1
n_neurons = 100
n_outputs = 1

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_outputs])


# In[7]:


cell =  tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)                        


rnn_outputs = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,dtype=tf.float32, name="hidden1")(X)
print(rnn_outputs.get_shape())


stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons], name='reshape1')
stacked_outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs,name="hidden2")(stacked_rnn_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs], name='reshape2')


learning_rate = 0.001

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # MSE
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

n_iterations = 1500
batch_size = 50
save_path =os.path.join(dir_path,"model","recurrent_sinus_model")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for iteration in range(n_iterations):
        X_batch, y_batch = next_batch(batch_size, n_steps)
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        if iteration % 100 == 0:
            mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            print(iteration, "\tMSE:", mse)

    saver.save(sess, save_path)


with tf.Session() as sess:                      
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)  

    X_new = time_series(np.array(t_instance[:-1].reshape(-1, n_steps, n_inputs)))
    y_pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_new})


plt.title("Testing the model", fontsize=14)
plt.plot(t_instance[:-1], time_series(t_instance[:-1]), "bo", markersize=10, label="instance")
plt.plot(t_instance[1:], time_series(t_instance[1:]), "w*", markersize=10, label="target")
plt.plot(t_instance[1:], y_pred[0,:,0], "r.", markersize=10, label="prediction")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlabel("Time")

plt.show()


# In[ ]:


with tf.Session() as sess:                      
    saver.restore(sess, save_path)  

    X_new = time_series(np.array(t.reshape(-1, n_steps, n_inputs)))
    y_pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_new})



plt.title("A time series (generated)", fontsize=14)
plt.plot(t, time_series(t), label=r"original",linewidth=5,c='r')
plt.plot(t[:-1], time_series(t[:-1]), "b-", linewidth=3, label="A training instance")
plt.legend(loc="lower left", fontsize=14)

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
rnn_outputs, rnn_states  = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,dtype=tf.float32, name="hidden1", return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(X)
```

instead of

```
rnn_outputs = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell,dtype=tf.float32, name="hidden1")(X)
```

so the parameter `return_sequences=True` make the RNN return the time series as well, and well, this is the point.